# I can only get the value of only one attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code and I would like it when the mouse goes over the `image 01` it takes the `date-id` of `Image 01` when it passes in `Image 02` it takes the `date-id` of `Image 02`. But for some reason it does not matter over which image i pass the mouse it just takes the `date-id` of the `image 01`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var me = jQuery(this);


  jQuery(".post-thumb").on("mouseover", function() {
    var data_id2 = jQuery('img', me).attr("data-id");
    console.log(data_id2);

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row list-group">
  <div class="item large-3 medium-6 columns end group-item-grid-default">
    <div class="post thumb-border" style="height: 20px;">
      <div class="post-thumb">

        <img src="image01.jpg" alt="Image 01" data-id="000001">


      </div>
      <!--post-thumb-->
    </div>
    <!--post thumb-border-->
  </div>
  <!--item-->
  <div class="item large-3 medium-6 columns end group-item-grid-default">
    <div class="post thumb-border" style="height: 20px;">
      <div class="post-thumb">

        <img src="image02.jpg" alt="Image 02" data-id="000002">


      </div>
      <!--post-thumb-->
    </div>
    <!--post thumb-border-->
  </div>
  <!--item-->
</div>
<!--item-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are declaring `me` out side of the event (`mouseover`) handler function, it's not changing when the event fires.  Declare `me` inside of the event handler function:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".post-thumb").on("mouseover", function() {
    var me = jQuery(this);
    var data_id2 = jQuery('img', me).attr("data-id");
    console.log(data_id2);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row list-group">
  <div class="item large-3 medium-6 columns end group-item-grid-default">
    <div class="post thumb-border" style="height: 277px;">
      <div class="post-thumb">
        <img src="image01.jpg" alt="Image 01" data-id="000001">
      </div>
      <!--post-thumb-->
    </div>
    <!--post thumb-border-->
  </div>
  <!--item-->
  <div class="item large-3 medium-6 columns end group-item-grid-default">
    <div class="post thumb-border" style="height: 277px;">
      <div class="post-thumb">
        <img src="image02.jpg" alt="Image 02" data-id="000002">
      </div>
      <!--post-thumb-->
    </div>
    <!--post thumb-border-->
  </div>
  <!--item-->
</div>
<!--item-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the `img` of currently hovered item. You can do `$(this).find('img')` .

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {


  jQuery(".post-thumb").on("mouseover", function() {
    var data_id2 = jQuery(this).find('img').attr("data-id");
    console.log(data_id2);

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row list-group">
  <div class="item large-3 medium-6 columns end group-item-grid-default">
    <div class="post thumb-border" style="height: 277px;">
      <div class="post-thumb">

        <img src="image01.jpg" alt="Image 01" data-id="000001">


      </div>
      <!--post-thumb-->
    </div>
    <!--post thumb-border-->
  </div>
  <!--item-->
  <div class="item large-3 medium-6 columns end group-item-grid-default">
    <div class="post thumb-border" style="height: 277px;">
      <div class="post-thumb">

        <img src="image02.jpg" alt="Image 02" data-id="000002">


      </div>
      <!--post-thumb-->
    </div>
    <!--post thumb-border-->
  </div>
  <!--item-->
</div>
<!--item-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It was due to the `this` is come from when the document loaded,it should come from the `mouseover` event

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery(".post-thumb").on("mouseover", function() {
    var data_id2 = jQuery('img', this).attr("data-id");
    console.log(data_id2);

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row list-group">
  <div class="item large-3 medium-6 columns end group-item-grid-default">
    <div class="post thumb-border" style="height: 277px;">
      <div class="post-thumb">

        <img src="image01.jpg" alt="Image 01" data-id="000001">


      </div>
      <!--post-thumb-->
    </div>
    <!--post thumb-border-->
  </div>
  <!--item-->
  <div class="item large-3 medium-6 columns end group-item-grid-default">
    <div class="post thumb-border" style="height: 277px;">
      <div class="post-thumb">

        <img src="image02.jpg" alt="Image 02" data-id="000002">


      </div>
      <!--post-thumb-->
    </div>
    <!--post thumb-border-->
  </div>
  <!--item-->
</div>
<!--item-->
</div>
```